# combo does not load values after form load in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a form where I need to display data in the combo box. Data is saved in database but when I open the form again the data disappears. 
following is the code. Please help in fixing.

```
Private Sub ReqEntryForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)


            SearchOnWarehseAdapterFillDropDown()
            cboDivision.DropDownStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraComboStyle.DropDownList
            cmbJobCode.DropDownStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraComboStyle.DropDownList

            End Sub



            Private Sub SearchOnWarehseAdapterFillDropDown()
                            ' Wizard Generated Search Method
                            ' You will need to call this method from another method in custom code
                            ' For example, [Form]_Load or [Button]_Click

                            Dim recSelected As Boolean
                            Dim whereClause As String = string.empty
                            Dim dsWarehseAdapter As System.Data.DataSet = Epicor.Mfg.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(Me.oTrans, "WarehseAdapter", recSelected, false, whereClause)
                            If recSelected Then
                                            ' Set EpiUltraCombo Properties
                                            Me.cboDivision.ValueMember = "WarehouseCode"
                                            Me.cboDivision.DataSource = dsWarehseAdapter
                                            Me.cboDivision.DisplayMember = "Description"
                                            Dim fields() As String = New String() {"Description"}
                                            Me.cboDivision.SetColumnFilter(fields)
                            End If
            End Sub

            Private Sub SearchOnWhseBinAdapterFillDropDown(row as Datarow)
                            ' Wizard Generated Search Method
                            ' You will need to call this method from another method in custom code
                            ' For example, [Form]_Load or [Button]_Click

                            Dim recSelected As Boolean
                            Dim whereClause As String = "WarehouseCode = '" + row("Character02")+ "'"
                            Dim dsWhseBinAdapter As System.Data.DataSet = Epicor.Mfg.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(Me.oTrans, "WhseBinAdapter", recSelected, false, whereClause)
                            If recSelected Then
                                            ' Set EpiUltraCombo Properties
                                            Me.cmbJobCode.ValueMember = "Description"
                                            Me.cmbJobCode.DataSource = dsWhseBinAdapter
                                            Me.cmbJobCode.DisplayMember = "Description"
                                            Dim fields() As String = New String() {"Description"}
                                            Me.cmbJobCode.SetColumnFilter(fields)
                            End If
            End Sub
            'dim iscode as boolean
            Private Sub ReqHead_AfterFieldChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
                            ' ** Argument Properties and Uses **
                            ' args.Row("FieldName")
                            ' args.Column, args.ProposedValue, args.Row
                            ' Add Event Handler Code
'               if iscode = true then
'               return
'               end if 
'               iscode = true
                                Select Case args.Column.ColumnName
                                                Case "Character02"
                                                SearchOnWhseBinAdapterFillDropDown(args.row)
                                                End Select
                'iscode = false    
                End Sub
```

Comment: You should debug the code to see where the error is

Comment: There is no error when I debug the code. Whenever I close the screen and reopen , the value does not appear, whereas it is saved in the database.

Comment: Dear all, This code is epicor code. Do i need to add the code in epinotification. How do i do the same. Please help me out...